# Using an NIST Calibrated Thermistor Meter with uncalibrated or unknown probes

Tags: measurements, sensors, temperature

Background:

I recently purchased a NIST calibrated thermistor meter for measuring temperature at work.  This [Digisense (20250-94)](https://www.coleparmer.com/i/digi-sense-thermistor-thermometer-2-input-data-logging-nist-traceable-calibration/2025094) meter came from a seemingly reputable company, Cole Parmer, and we paid extra to get one that had been calibrated.

Unfortunately the meter arrived without probes attached as shown in the photo (my fault for assuming).  Further, the manual says absolutely nothing about what probes are compatible with the meter, only mentioning that there is a stereo jack output. I am able to connect things to a header and jack that I have attached to the meter, but not sure I can trust anything it says.  The only "calibration" available to the meter is setting an offset to the temperature value of the probe.

I looked on the cole parmer website, and none of the [thermistor probes](https://www.coleparmer.com/p/digi-sense-400-series-thermistor-probes/47431) that they sell come with calibration data or specs, although I might assume they are compatible with this Digisense meter.  Looking at the NIST calibration sheet, it seems the [calibration company](https://www.innocalsolutions.com) used a *"thermistor probe simulator"* *according to customer requirements*, which seems a bit wonky to me. I have written and called their customer support and no replies/on hold forever - which is why I am here asking the real experts :)

My questions:

- should I trust a company (cole parmer) if they are not supplying
  the thermistor data with their probes?
- since thermistors have highly non-linear properties, is it likely a very bad idea to use any thermistor probe other than what is supplied by the manufacturer?
- what should I expect from a good thermistor meter if I want to get trustworthy results from it?

Photo of meter:

[image]

Comment: So, without a calibrated complete system then nothing will be calibrated.

Comment: Thermistor and RTD probes and associated electronics both have standard curves for a given sensor type, and tolerance grades specifying deviation from those curves. Both parts are combined to get the system tolerances. So you have half a system, just buy the probe you need, of the exact type for which you calibrated, and for the accuracy class that's appropriate when you add up all the tolerances. Aside from that, Cole Parmer is an mega co. that re-sells OEM's. They've grown a lot thru acquisition this past decade. Personal experience: they've gotten a little too big, at times sloppy, but okay